# Spring Property place holder: reading value from external property file fails

Tags: spring, properties, log4j

I am trying to read logpath from external property file.

I have below spring configuration. I am using spring 2, maven.

beans-config.xml

```
<bean id="loglocation" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location">
 <value>file:///D:/logpath.properties</value>
 </property>
```

**logpath.properties**

```html
logpath=D:/logs/myproject.log
```

**log4j.properties**

```html
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=${logpath}
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I dont know how to pass the log path from logpath.property file to the placeholder ${logpath}in log4j.prop.  Am I missing anything in beans configuration xml? Any help

Comment: log4j is not managed by Spring, you'll need to set the path in log4j.properties